# Ionic Framework Typescript: Callback function is not able to access `this` variables

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, ionic-framework, ionic3

Callback function is not able to access `this` variables.

Specifically I'm working with d3.request and ionic 3. The d3.request is able to make a rest call but then I can't assign the response to my this.data variable. I'm able to console.log(response)

How can I access this.variables?

```
d3Request.request('http://47.184.52.10:8000/xyplot/')
  .header('Content-Type', 'application/json' )
  .post(JSON.stringify({'envelope':this.envelope,'chartTime': this.chartTime}),
      function(d){
          console.log(d.response);
          console.log(this.data) /*<---this.data*/
      })
```

brings an error 'Cannot read property 'data' of undefined'

How can I resolve this issue so that my d3.request response can be assigned to a this.variable??

Answer (score 3):

**this** isn't defined inside the function. Use arrow functions to solve this

```
d3Request.request('http://47.184.52.10:8000/xyplot/')
  .header('Content-Type', 'application/json' )
  .post(JSON.stringify({'envelope':this.envelope,'chartTime': this.chartTime}),
      d => {
          console.log(d.response);
          console.log(this.data) /*<---this.data*/
      })
```